# CAN bus signal integrity

Tags: signal, can, signal-integrity

The channels are CAN_H (red), CAN_L (blue), and CAN_H-CAN_L (brown).

It can be observed in the diagram below that CAN_H-CAN_L has an acceptable signal shape. However, both CAN_H and CAN_L look poorly to me. And actually the device is not running in a noisy environment. I have two questions:

1. Do you think signal integrity is an issue here?
2. CAN_H-CAN_L sometimes has high voltage level of 1.65 V (left side part), while sometimes it has a high level of 2.06 V (right side part). Do you think this is a problem?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. No. The [differential signalling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling) is performing as intended.
2. No. As long as the "[common mode voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common-mode_signal)" does not exceed the ratings of the transceiver. And the maximum DC ratings, which for a CAN transceiver like the [MCP2551](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21667f.pdf) is -42 V to +42 V.

The twisted pair cable and the differential signalling mode make the single-end signals look like gibberish while the differential signal is not affected by the noise. You will have the occasional corrupt frame, but CAN has [several features](https://www.kvaser.com/can-protocol-tutorial/) to ensure only correct frames are accepted and bad ones are re-transmitted.

- CRC to detect bit errors.
- Error frames. When *one* node detects an error, it sends an error frame, and this frame forces the bus dominant longer than the bit stuffing rule. All nodes see this.
- Automatic re-transmit until the error limit.

I have one of these images as well. These are textbook images on differential signalling. This kind of noise is inevitable in systems with electromechanical or high power switching components.

[image: CAN bus differential textbook image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you think isolation is needed when the can cable is around 5 meters long?

Comment: @richieqianle I recommend galvanic isolation for every node. It's not expensive (ic's: sn6501, si8621), especially not if it can save you trouble. However, it is not essential to CAN bus functioning. Look up split termination and have the nodes properly grounded.